# Django get all rows of models identified by foreign key

Tags: django

The European privacy policy requires to give information which data a website has about a user.

With Django 1.11. I can get all relations to a specific user by  `._meta.get_fields`. Is there a nice way to iterate over the relations and get the actual data as rows?

This is what my relations look like:

```
In [1]: from test_project.people.models import Profile
   ...: user = Profile.objects.get(id=1000) 
   ...: user._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True)
   ...: 
Out[1]: 
(<ManyToOneRel: admin.logentry>,
 <ManyToOneRel: avatar.avatar>,
 <ManyToOneRel: dialogos.comment>,
 <ManyToOneRel: agon_ratings.rating>,
 <ManyToOneRel: announcements.announcement>,
 <ManyToOneRel: announcements.dismissal>,
 <ManyToOneRel: actstream.follow>,
 <ManyToManyRel: user_messages.thread>,
 <ManyToManyRel: user_messages.thread>,
 <ManyToOneRel: user_messages.groupmemberthread>,
 <ManyToOneRel: user_messages.userthread>,
 <ManyToOneRel: user_messages.message>,
 <OneToOneRel: tastypie.apikey>,
 <ManyToOneRel: guardian.userobjectpermission>,
 <ManyToOneRel: oauth2_provider.application>,
 <ManyToOneRel: oauth2_provider.grant>,
 <ManyToOneRel: oauth2_provider.accesstoken>,
 <ManyToOneRel: oauth2_provider.refreshtoken>,
 <ManyToOneRel: oauth2_provider.idtoken>,
 <ManyToOneRel: invitations.invitation>,
 <ManyToOneRel: account.emailaddress>,
 <ManyToOneRel: socialaccount.socialaccount>,
 <ManyToOneRel: base.contactrole>,
 <ManyToOneRel: base.resourcebase>,
 <ManyToManyRel: base.resourcebase>,
 <ManyToOneRel: layers.uploadsession>,
 <ManyToOneRel: maps.mapsnapshot>,
 <ManyToOneRel: people.profile_groups>,
 <ManyToOneRel: people.profile_user_permissions>,
 <ManyToOneRel: groups.groupmember>,
 <ManyToManyRel: services.service>,
 <ManyToOneRel: services.serviceprofilerole>,
 <ManyToOneRel: upload.upload>,
 <ManyToOneRel: favorite.favorite>,
 <ManyToOneRel: monitoring.notificationreceiver>,
 <ManyToOneRel: mapster_adapter.mapstoreresource>,
 <ManyToOneRel: pinax_notifications.noticesetting>,
 <django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: password>,
 <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: last_login>,
 <django.db.models.fields.BooleanField: is_superuser>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: username>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: first_name>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: last_name>,
 <django.db.models.fields.EmailField: email>,
 <django.db.models.fields.BooleanField: is_staff>,
 <django.db.models.fields.BooleanField: is_active>,
 <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: date_joined>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: organization>,
 <django.db.models.fields.TextField: profile>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: position>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: voice>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: fax>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: delivery>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: city>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: area>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: zipcode>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: country>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: language>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: timezone>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: groups>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: user_permissions>,
 <taggit.managers.TaggableManager: keywords>,
 <django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation: tagged_items>,
 <django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation: actor_actions>,
 <django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation: target_actions>,
 <django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation: action_object_actions>)
```

I would look for something like this (PseudoCode)

```
allUserData = user._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True)
for dat in allUserData:
    currentRow = dat.objects.filter(FK_FIELD_WHICH_IS_LINKED=1000)
    print(currentRow)
```

In case there is already a third-party app or another shell approach I'm open ear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the `user` has the field as attribute (if not, it can be discarded as some `ManyToOneRel` are duplicating direct fields on the model):

```
for field in user._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True):
    if hasattr(user, field.name):
        print(field.name, getattr(user, field.name))
```

You'll want to test the result of `getattr(user, field.name))` if it's iterable then you'll want to iterate through the results. And for each of the results you'll want to redo the same (if it's a model, you probably want to fetch all the fields again).

Comment: do you by chance know if I can easily get the name of the fk (from the linked foreign model)?

Comment: yes, it's `field.field_name` for relationship fields (FK and 1-to-1). Not sure for m2m, because it's probably pointing to the intermediate table.